# Bitcoin Address can't be found of client?

Tags: address

So, I'm a total noob to Bitcoin and have just finished installing it and have looked under all of the settings and cannot find the address. This is a little concerning. If I am missing something PLEASE correct/help me. I have seen in older versions that the address is right there on the GUI but I still can't find mine. I'm on version 0.7.2 if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Under the tab 'Receive Coins', click 'New Address'